# sed: how to replace line if found or append to end of file if not found?

Tags: linux, command-line, sed, awk

With a single input file that only contains comments (starting with #) and VARIABLE=value lines, is it possible to replace a value for a single variable if found and, otherwise, append the pair to the end of file if not found?

My current method works by deleting it in a first pass, then appending it to the end of the file in a second pass, but this method messes up the line ordering (and is also two different commands):

```
sed -r "/^FOOBAR=.*$/d"      -i samefile &&
sed -r "$ a\FOOBAR=newvalue" -i samefile
```

Is there anyway to do this, ie. keeping line order, in a single sed line? If some other utility (awk, ...) does this, I'ld take it over sed.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It's actually quite simple with `sed`: if a line matches just copy it to the `h`old space then `s`ubstitute the value.
On the la`$`t line e`x`change hold space and pattern space then check if the latter is empty. If it's not empty, it means the substitution was already made so nothing to do. If it's empty, that means no match was found so replace the pattern space with the desired *variable=value* then append to the current line in the hold buffer. Finally, e`x`change again:

```
sed '/^FOOBAR=/{h;s/=.*/=newvalue/};${x;/^$/{s//FOOBAR=newvalue/;H};x}' infile
```

The above is `gnu sed` syntax. Portable:

```
sed '/^FOOBAR=/{
h
s/=.*/=newvalue/
}
${
x
/^$/{
s//FOOBAR=newvalue/
H
}
x
}' infile
```

Comment: How would this look like if `newvalue` is stored in a variable?

Comment: `sed "/^${varName}=/{h;s/=.*/=${varValue}/};\${x;/^$/{s//${varName}=${varValue}/;H};x}" ${VARFILE}` with variables, double quotes to allow for variable substitution and and escaping a `$` that is not a substitution at this point, additionally if you value is stored in `$$varName` : `sed "/^${varName}=/{h;s/=.*/=${!varName}/};\${x;/^$/{s//${varName}=${!varName}/;H};x}" ${VARFILE}`

Comment: This solution is not 'simple' lol. But it works. sed man pages are not the easiest things to sift through, it would be really helpful if you could detail the effect of every section of the expression :)

Comment: Great solution! If you prefer to keep existing line in place!

Comment: the append will fail if the file has no lines like when a file was  just created by  touch.

Comment: one could put this before the sed command to make sure file has at least one line.  `tail -c1 infile | read -r _ || echo >> infile`  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34865616/4695378

Answer (score 36):

Here is a simpler `sed` approach, as I don't find `sed` `hold space` easy to work with. If you are comfortable with `hold space`, using don_crissti's approach gives additional opportunity to preserve anything from the existing line and its position as well.

In the below approach, you just print all but the line that you want to drop and then at the end, append the replacement.

```
sed -n -e '/^FOOBAR=/!p' -e '$aFOOBAR=newvalue' infile
```

The line gets moved to the end of the file as pointed out by @alek, so make sure that this is acceptable in your case.

Comment: This version is very good if you plan to update a file that may have an existing but outdated value.

Comment: Great answer! If you don't mind that the existing line is moved to the end. Thanks!
I prefer to put it in one parameter: `sed -nr '/^FOOBAR=/!p;$aFOOBAR=newvalue' infile`

Comment: This didn’t work for me as long as the file was completely empty (just created with `touch`) using `sed (GNU sed) 4.7
Packaged by Debian`. The file just stayed empty with no error message.

Comment: @DanielBöhmer I just happened to hit this a couple of days back and understand that this is normal behavior for sed, considering how it is line oriented (when empty, there are no lines). One workaround is to start with a dummy line that will always be removed.

Comment: I tried this option and I couldn't get it to work with in-place editing (`-i`). It seemed to duplicate previous lines.

Comment: @Danny When I tried using `gsed` with `-i` option on mac, it worked just fine. Make sure you are using a GNU version of sed.

Comment: @haridsv Odd, I was testing on a CentOS 7 box, so I would have been using GNU sed. I'll have to play with it again and see if I was making on error. I ended up having to use don_crissti's method to get it working yesterday.

Comment: @Danny, I was able to use it like `sed -i -n -e ...`

Answer (score 20):

This can probably be shortened. It's not a single sed command and it also uses grep, but this seems to be basically what you're wanting. It's a single line, and it edits the file in-place (no temp files).

```
grep -q "^FOOBAR=" file && sed "s/^FOOBAR=.*/FOOBAR=newvalue/" -i file || 
    sed "$ a\FOOBAR=newvalue" -i file
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply use `grep` and `echo` to create an empty record :

```
grep -q '^FOOBAR=' somefile || echo 'FOOBAR=VALUE' >> somefile
sed -i 's/FOOBAR=.*$/FOOBAR=VALUE/' somefile
```

Each line escapes with error code zero.

Comment: You lose line ordering while adding an extra commands and `grep` and `echo`

Comment: Indeed if you insert the new items at the end of file, but keep ordering if you replace a old value.

Comment: This solution is much more understandable to someone who doesn't have detailed knowledge of sed or grep

Answer (score 2):

Based on the other answers, if what you want to do is replace a variable's value if that variable is present in the file and append it to the end of the file if it is not (which is not what your posted `sed` commands do), you could try this:

```
perl -ne '$c=1 if s/^FOOBAR=.*$/FOOBAR=newvalue/;  
             print; 
             END{print "FOOBAR=newvalue" unless $c==1}' file > tmpfile && 
mv tmpfile file
```

Comment: You can use Perl’s `-i` switch to edit the file in place and save the hassle of managing a temp file

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit easier in awk, although the "in place editing" is not automatic:

```
awk -v varname="FOOBAR" -v newval="newvalue" '
    BEGIN {FS = OFS = "="}
    $1 == varname {$2 = newval; found = 1}
    {print}
    END {if (! found) {print varname, newval}}
' file > tempfile &&
mv tempfile file
```

Comment: ``equation=E=mc²``.  This chokes if the old value contains an `=`.

Comment: True. Instead of `$2 = newval`, could use `$0 = $1 OFS newval`

Answer (score 0):

As a programmer not accustomed to shell scripts it was easier to construct a more readable (for me) command by first deleting any existing match and then appending the value to the end of file

##### my-script.sh

```sh
CALCULATED_VALUE="some_end_result"

# delete any old value and append the new one
sed -i '' '/^MY_ENV_VAR/d' .env || true
echo "MY_ENV_VAR=${CALCULATED_VALUE}" >> .env
```

`sed -i ''` is because I'm on a macos, I think on ubuntu it'll be just `sed -i`

---

```sh
sed -i '' '/^MY_ENV_VAR/d' .env || true
```

Matches the line I want to update and deletes it if it exists. `|| true` covers cases where a matching line does not exist in `.env`

```sh
echo "MY_ENV_VAR=${CALCULATED_VALUE}" >> .env
```

Adds the new line to the end of file

Comment: This is just a more convoluted way than my original post ;-) Also, '|| true' shouldn't be necessary (macOs specific?)

Answer (score -1):

for me I tried most of the above solutions and they didn't work using `sed (GNU sed) 4.4`! So I tried something similar to @snapshoe solution but a bit different:

```
envVar=FOOBAR
envVal=newvalue
file=samefile
grep -q "^${envVar}=" ${file} && sed -i -e "s/^${envVar}=.*/${envVar}=${envVal}/g" ${file} || echo "${envVar}=${envVal}" >> ${file}
```

This will replace FOOBAR if found or append to end of file if not found

one line:
`envVar=FOOBAR && envVal=newvalue && file=samefile && grep -q "^${envVar}=" ${file} && sed -i -e "s/^${envVar}=.*/${envVar}=${envVal}/g" ${file} || echo "${envVar}=${envVal}" >> ${file}`

Comment: Question asks for a one liner. Even @snapshoe didn't do it as a one-liner.

Comment: @BlakBat you do realize that if you add `&&` after each var instead of new line or if you replace the vars with string it is then one line! learn command line before down voting answers

Comment: One line = One command. && means multiple commands. Learn to be agreable and not to post an anecdotal answer ("didn't work for me yada yada"). BTW, pretty much sure it works with sed 4.4 (used on debian:stretch)

Answer (score -1):

sed hold can handle one entry only. I enhanced glenn jackman's answer to handle multiple entries:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = "="}{idx=0;
  varname[++idx]="FOOBAR1";newval[idx]="val1";
  varname[++idx]="FOOBAR2";newval[idx]="val2";
  ...
}
{for (i in varname){if ($1 == varname[i]){sub($2".*",newval[i]);found[i]=1;}}print}
END {for (i in varname){if (!found[i]) print varname[i], newval[i]}
}' file > tempfile && cp tempfile file && rm tempfile
```

Comment: This is an interesting contribution. However, beware of `sub()`. This will choke if the old value (`$2`) is a regular expression that doesn’t match itself (e.g., `a[b]` or `1+2`), or if it is a substring of the variable name (e.g., `cat=c` or `dog=o`).

Answer (score -2):

to do this with perl and in-place this works fine for me:

```
grep ^FOOBAR= my.file && perl -i -ple "s/^FOOBAR=.+/FOOBAR=newvalue/g" my.file || echo FOOBAR=newvalue >> my.file
```

Comment: This answer is **bad** in so many ways!  `grep` and `echo` and `perl` instead of doing everything in `perl`?  Also, writing to a file (`>> my.file`) as you're reading from it (`grep my.file`)?

Answer (score -2):

Actually works with the following:

`sed -i '/^FOOBAR=/{h;s/=.*/=newvalue/};${x;/^$/{s//FOOBAR=newvalue/;H};x}' infile`

In the answer choosen -i is missing.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)